# Map default value

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, default-value

I'm looking for something like default value for Map.

```
m = new Map();
//m.setDefVal([]); -- how to write this line???
console.log(m[whatever]);
```

Now the result is Undefined but I want to get empty array [].

Comment: An empty array is empty, and thus has no element at index `[0]`

Comment: `m[whatever] || []`

Comment: It is important to distinguish if you want the same array or a new array to be returned as the default value of your Map for any given key. This is entirely dependent on your requirements which one you want but it is important to understand and choose the one that fits your needs. Some of the below answers assume one or the other requirement so you will want to be careful that the choice they implement is really the one that actually suits your needs.

Comment: Also probably important to distinguish if you want the default value to automatically be set on the Map when you attempt to get it or if you want a new instance of the default value to be returned each time. The below responses also make assumptions in this regard.

Comment: Lastly, if you are using a Map it is good practice to stick to the map getter/setter syntax: m.get(whatever) instead of m[whatever]. m[whatever] might not do what you expect in certain scenarios: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#setting_object_properties

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First of all to answer the question regarding the standard `Map`: Javascript `Map` as proposed in ECMAScript 2015 does not include a setter for default values. This, however, does not restrain you from implementing the function yourself.

If you just want to print a list, whenever m[whatever] is undefined, you can just:
`console.log(m.get('whatever') || []);`
as pointed out by Li357 in his comment.

If you want to reuse this functionality, you could also encapsulate this into a function like:

```js
function getMapValue(map, key) {
    return map.get(key) || [];
}

// And use it like:
const m = new Map();
console.log(getMapValue(m, 'whatever'));
```

If this, however, does not satisfy your needs and you really want a map that has a default value you can write your own Map class for it like:

```js
class MapWithDefault extends Map {
  get(key) {
    if (!this.has(key)) {
      this.set(key, this.default());
    }
    return super.get(key);
  }
  
  constructor(defaultFunction, entries) {
    super(entries);
    this.default = defaultFunction;
  }
}

// And use it like:
const m = new MapWithDefault(() => []);
m.get('whatever').push('you');
m.get('whatever').push('want');
console.log(m.get('whatever')); // ['you', 'want']
```

Comment: I believe that you should support what `Map` constructor already requires, don't you?

Comment: In the class implementation you pass a new object and use it as a reference so every time we use the m.get we return the same object. I think you should use defaultValue as a function that returns a new instance of array.

Comment: An alternative implementation of `get` would be to use `if (!this.get(key) this.set(key, this.default());`. This would allow convenient one-liners like `m.get('key').push(newValue)`, at the expense of making the `get` method mutate the object, which is slightly awkward

Comment: @YiJiang's approach is consistent with Python's defaultdict and less surprising.  I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: The solution with `map.get(key) || []` should not be used as it gives wrong results if `key` is mapped to a falsy value, like `0`.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2022, `Map.prototype.emplace` has reached [stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-upsert).

As it says on the proposal page, a polyfill is available in the [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) library.

Answer (score 3):

### Most straightforward implementation:

Here's a simple `MapWithDefault` class that extends the built-in `Map`.

The clever trick is here is using [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) for specifying the default value, resulting in a nice and readable syntax:

(The snippets below use **TypeScript** to provide type-safety, but this is optional, you can remove the type annotations if you wish.)

`mapWithDefault.ts`:

```js
export const DEFAULT = Symbol();
export class MapWithDefault<K, V> extends Map<K | typeof DEFAULT, V> {
    get(key: K): V {
        return super.has(key)
            ? super.get(key)
            : super.get(DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
import { MapWithDefault, DEFAULT } from './mapWithDefault';

const map = new MapWithDefault<number, string>([
    [404, 'Not found!'],
    [403, 'Forbidden!'],
    [DEFAULT, 'Unknown error'],
]);

console.log(map.get(404)); // "Not found!"
console.log(map.get(123)); // "Unknown error"
```

Comment: This implementation's `get` does not typecheck with TypeScript 5.1, but the following method does:

`get(key: K): V { return super.get(key) ?? (super.get(DEFAULT) as V); }`

Answer (score 2):

For my purposes, I thought it would be more clear to have a `DefaultMap` class that extended a normal `Map` and added additional methods. This is really nice because it leads to more declarative code. Meaning that when you declare a new `Map`, not only do you declare the type of the keys and the type of the values, you also declare the default value.

As a quick example:

```
// Using a primitive as a default value:
const myMap1 = new DefaultMap<string, number>(123);
const myMap1Value = myMap1.getAndSetDefault("some_key"); // Value is 123

// Using a factory function to generate a default value:
const myMap2 = new DefaultMap<string, number, [foo: Foo]>(
  (foo) => foo.bar
);
const foo = new Foo();
const myMap2Value = myMap2.getAndSetDefault("some_key", foo); // Value is foo.bar
```

The code is below:

````
import { isFunction, isPrimitive } from "../functions/types";

/**
 * `DefaultMap` is a data structure that makes working with default values easier. It extends a
 * `Map` and adds additional methods.
 *
 * It is a common pattern to look up a value in a `Map`, and then, if the value does not exist, set
 * a default value for the key, and then return the default value. `DefaultMap` abstracts this
 * operation away by providing the `getAndSetDefault` method.
 *
 * Using a `DefaultMap` is nice because it makes code more declarative, since you specify what the
 * default value is alongside the types of the keys/values.
 *
 * When instantiating a new `DefaultMap`, you must specify default value as the first argument. (The
 * default value is the initial value that will be assigned to every new entry in the
 * `getAndSetDefault` method.) For example:
 *
 * ```ts
 * // Initializes a new empty DefaultMap with a default value of "foo".
 * const defaultMapWithString = new DefaultMap<string, string>("foo");
 *
 * const value = defaultMapWithString.getAndSetDefault("bar");
 * // value is now "foo" and an entry for "bar" is now set.
 * ```
 *
 * Sometimes, instead of having a static initial value for every entry in the map, you will want a
 * dynamic initial value that is contingent upon the key or some other variable. In these cases, you
 * can instead specify that the `DefaultMap` should run a function that will return the initial
 * value. (This is referred to as a "factory function".) For example:
 *
 * ```ts
 * // Initializes a new empty DefaultMap with a default value based on "someGlobalVariable".
 * const factoryFunction = () => someGlobalVariable ? 0 : 1;
 * const defaultMapWithFactoryFunction = new DefaultMap<string, string>(factoryFunction);
 * ```
 *
 * Note that in TypeScript and Lua, booleans, numbers, and strings are "passed by value". This means
 * that when the `DefaultMap` creates a new entry, if the default value is one of these 3 types, the
 * values will be copied. On the other hand, arrays and maps and other complex data structures are
 * "passed by reference". This means that when the `DefaultMap` creates a new entry, if the default
 * value is an array, then it would not be copied. Instead, the same shared array would be assigned
 * to every entry. Thus, to solve this problem, any variable that is passed by reference must be
 * created using a factory function to ensure that each copy is unique. For example:
 *
 * ```ts
 * // Initializes a new empty DefaultMap with a default value of a new empty array.
 * const factoryFunction = () => [];
 * const defaultMapWithArray = new DefaultMap<string, string[]>(factoryFunction);
 * ```
 *
 * In the previous two examples, the factory functions did not have any arguments. But you can also
 * specify a factory function that takes one or more arguments:
 *
 * ```ts
 * const factoryFunction = (arg: boolean) => arg ? 0 : 1;
 * const defaultMapWithArg = new DefaultMap<string, string, [arg: boolean]>(factoryFunction);
 * ```
 *
 * Similar to a normal `Map`, you can also include an initializer list in the constructor as the
 * second argument:
 *
 * ```ts
 * // Initializes a DefaultMap with a default value of "foo" and some initial values.
 * const defaultMapWithInitialValues = new DefaultMap<string, string>("foo", [
 *   ["a1", "a2"],
 *   ["b1", "b2"],
 * ], );
 * ```
 *
 * Finally, note that `DefaultMap` has the following additional utility methods:
 *
 * - `getAndSetDefault` - The method that is called inside the overridden `get` method. In most
 *   cases, you can use the overridden `get` method instead of calling this function directly.
 *   However, if a factory function was provided during instantiation, and the factory function has
 *   one or more arguments, then you must call this method instead (and provide the corresponding
 *   arguments).
 * - `getDefaultValue` - Returns the default value to be used for a new key. (If a factory function
 *   was provided during instantiation, this will execute the factory function.)
 * - `getConstructorArg` - Helper method for cloning the map. Returns either the default value or
 *   the reference to the factory function.
 */
export class DefaultMap<Key, Value, Args extends unknown[] = []> extends Map<
  Key,
  Value
> {
  private defaultValue: Value | undefined;
  private defaultValueFactory: FactoryFunction<Value, Args> | undefined;

  /**
   * See the main `DefaultMap` documentation:
   * https://isaacscript.github.io/isaacscript-common/other/classes/DefaultMap
   */
  constructor(
    defaultValueOrFactoryFunction: Value | FactoryFunction<Value, Args>,
    initializerArray?: Iterable<[Key, Value]>,
  ) {
    const argIsPrimitive = isPrimitive(defaultValueOrFactoryFunction);
    const argIsFunction = isFunction(defaultValueOrFactoryFunction);
    if (!argIsPrimitive && !argIsFunction) {
      error(
        `Failed to instantiate a DefaultMap since the provided default value was of type "${typeof defaultValueOrFactoryFunction}". This error usually means that you are trying to use an array (or some other non-primitive data structure that is passed by reference) as the default value. Instead, return the data structure in a factory function, like "() => []". See the DefaultMap documentation for more details.`,
      );
    }

    super(initializerArray);

    if (argIsFunction) {
      this.defaultValue = undefined;
      this.defaultValueFactory = defaultValueOrFactoryFunction;
    } else {
      this.defaultValue = defaultValueOrFactoryFunction;
      this.defaultValueFactory = undefined;
    }
  }

  /**
   * If the key exists, this will return the same thing as the normal `Map.get` method. Otherwise,
   * it will set a default value for the provided key, and then return the default value.
   */
  public getAndSetDefault(key: Key, ...args: Args): Value {
    const value = super.get(key);
    if (value !== undefined) {
      return value;
    }

    const defaultValue = this.getDefaultValue(...args);
    this.set(key, defaultValue);
    return defaultValue;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the default value to be used for a new key. (If a factory function was provided during
   * instantiation, this will execute the factory function.)
   */
  public getDefaultValue(...args: Args): Value {
    if (this.defaultValue !== undefined) {
      return this.defaultValue;
    }

    if (this.defaultValueFactory !== undefined) {
      return this.defaultValueFactory(...args);
    }

    error("A DefaultMap was incorrectly instantiated.");
  }

  /**
   * Helper method for cloning the map. Returns either the default value or a reference to the
   * factory function.
   */
  public getConstructorArg(): Value | FactoryFunction<Value, Args> {
    if (this.defaultValue !== undefined) {
      return this.defaultValue;
    }

    if (this.defaultValueFactory !== undefined) {
      return this.defaultValueFactory;
    }

    error("A DefaultMap was incorrectly instantiated.");
  }
}

// eslint-disable-next-line isaacscript/complete-sentences-jsdoc
/**
 * A function that creates the default value for your `DefaultMap`. For example, if it was a
 * `DefaultMap` containing maps, the factory function would be: `() => new Map()`
 */
export type FactoryFunction<V, Args extends unknown[]> = (...args: Args) => V;

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
function test() {
  // Boolean
  const myDefaultMapBoolean = new DefaultMap<string, boolean>(false);
  const myDefaultMapBooleanFactory = new DefaultMap<string, boolean>(
    () => false,
  );
  const myDefaultMapBooleanWithoutParams = new DefaultMap(false);

  // Number
  const myDefaultMapNumber = new DefaultMap<string, number>(123);
  const myDefaultMapNumberFactory = new DefaultMap<string, number>(() => 123);
  const myDefaultMapNumberWithoutParams = new DefaultMap(123);

  // String
  const myDefaultMapString = new DefaultMap<string, string>("foo");
  const myDefaultMapStringFactory = new DefaultMap<string, string>(() => "foo");
  const myDefaultMapStringWithoutParams = new DefaultMap("foo");

  // Array
  const myDefaultMapArray = new DefaultMap<string, string[]>(() => []);
  const myDefaultMapArrayWithoutParams = new DefaultMap(() => []);

  // Map
  const myDefaultMapMap = new DefaultMap<string, Map<string, string>>(
    () => new Map(),
  );
  const myDefaultMapMapWithoutParams = new DefaultMap(() => new Map());
}
/* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
````

Answer (score 1):

I also had a need for this, so I created a small extension of `Map` (linked [here](https://gist.github.com/romellem/56b23de24eeed3874498a418b0786968)) and also included below.

```js
class MapWithDefaultValues extends Map {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this._defaultGetValue = undefined;
    }

    setDefault(value) {
        this._defaultGetValue = value;
        return this;
    }

    clearDefault() {
        return this.setDefault(undefined);
    }

    get(key, ...rest) {
        if (super.has(key)) {
            return super.get(key);
        }

        let [defaultValue] = rest;
        // Allow for `get(key, undefined)` to override `this._defaultGetValue`
        if (rest.length === 0) {
            defaultValue = this._defaultGetValue;
        }

        return typeof defaultValue === 'function' ? defaultValue(key, this) : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Using a *function* as a defaultValue allows you to have computed defaults.

```js
const doubles = new MapWithDefaultValues([[1, 'two'], [2, 'four']]);
doubles.setDefault(key => typeof key === 'number' ? key * 2 : undefined);
doubles.get(1) // 'two'
doubles.get(5) // 10 (computed default)
```

The 2nd argument passed to the default also allows you to use the entire underlying `Map`, so you can do things like get the default value *and* `set()` it on the `Map`.

```js
const caps = new MapWithDefaultValues();
caps.size; // 0
caps.get('a', (key, map) => {
  const result = String(key).toUpperCase();
  map.set(key, result);
  return result;
}); // 'A'
caps.size; // 1
```